# How to send a note to recipients for an uploaded file to Google Drive?

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, google-drive-api, pydrive

I am with pyDrive to upload files to my Google Drive. I am able to upload files to any specific folder.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'myfile.txt', 'parents': [{"kind": "drive#fileLink","id": {FOLDER_ID}}]})
file1.SetContentFile('myfile.txt')
file1.Upload()
```

How can I share the uploaded file with other people and send a note to the recipients either using pyDrive or official Google Drive REST API?

Comment: I believe this is what yo are looking for: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing It has code for permissions setting in python as well

Answer (score 2):

This is available in pydrive via [InsertPermission](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html#pydrive.files.GoogleDriveFile.InsertPermission).

The act of creating a permission for a user or group email address will by default send a sharing email to that user or group.

See the Drive API documentation on [creating permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [Handling special metadata](https://googledrive.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/filemanagement.html#handling-special-metadata), more specifically: [InsertPermission](https://googledrive.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/filemanagement.html#insert-permissions).

You can share a document with a user (using their email address) like so:

```
# Add a read permission for the user with the specified email address.
permission = file1.InsertPermission({
                        'type': 'user',
                        'value': '<email@address.here>',
                        'role': 'reader'})


# You can check which permission settings a file has:
print(file1['permissions'])
```

Replace `reader` with `writer` if you want give the user write permission.

`InsertPermission` accepts all flags described in the official [API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert).

*Note*: PyDrive uses `v2` of the Google Drive API.